# Is it possible to restrict users to view only a specific set of columns in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Example: I have a basetable "wishfulthinking" with columns - a, b, c
I have user1, user2, user 3 [Note: user is also a role, meaning, user1 is role1 and user2 is role2...]

I would like to give all the above users access to all the tables (a,b,c) BUT,
user1 - should only be able to view a,b columns
user2 - should be able to view b,c columns and
user3 - should be able view a,c columns

What I have tried so far:
Materialised View: Created a view with only a,b columns and gave SELECT privilege to user1/role1.
login as user1 and try to select, i get the error - User user1 has no SELECT permission on table keyspace.wishfulthinking.

Now, when I give user1/role1 access to base table(wishfulthinking), the user will be able to get all the 3 columns instead of 2.

What am I missing here? Is it even possible or it wishful thinking? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use materialized views.

I would duplicate the table without the columns that the second user should not see and set select permissions on table1 for user1 and table2 for user2.

Comment: Would it not mean that I will need to write to two tables? Or is there trigger that I can set which will populate the second table? The first table is populated using kafka in near real time.

Comment: You would write two tables. This is a common approach in cassandra to duplicate your data.